# How to instrument jetty plugin from maven with open telemetry?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, open-telemetry

I am experimenting with adding open-telemetry to my Java projects.

I have a project where I have an API based on swagger-ui as a jersey-based servlet.

I normally run this using the jetty-maven plugin as a war:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <war>${project.build.directory}/main-api.war</war>
                </webApp>

                <scan>1</scan>
                <contextHandlers>
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                        <contextPath>/swagger-ui</contextPath>
                        <resourceBase>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/swagger-ui
                        </resourceBase>
                        <handler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler"/>
                    </contextHandler>
                </contextHandlers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

How can I add the  [opentelemetry-java-instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation%20opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) as java-agent to this proces?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<project>
  ...

  <properties>
    <opentelemetry.version>1.24.0</opentelemetry.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>download-opentelemetry-javaagent</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>io.opentelemetry.javaagent</groupId>
                  <artifactId>opentelemetry-javaagent</artifactId>
                  <version>${opentelemetry.version}</version>
                  <destFileName>opentelemetry-javaagent.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          ...
          <jvmArgs>
            <jvmArg>-javaagent:${project.build.directory}/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar</jvmArg>
          </jvmArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```